# Vue animate restart

Tags: css, vue.js, animation

I have problem with Vue and animations.
When new Vue app is attaching to html then animation are restarting.

Example:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {}
  });
}, 3000);
```

https://codepen.io/ArturAny/pen/VwPNwZM

I have hybrid app where some elements are in Vue and others are in html.
How to fix/disable restarting animation on vue mounting?

Comment: Is it imperative you have the same content inside the target `#app` div? by removing it and placing inside a Vue component, you will only have it animate in once

Comment: I can't move content. Page is already running in production. About half of html code is generated with php and half are vue components. 
Next time i will do about more clear concept with full SPA but now i must fix that :).

Answer (score 1):

If you can't move the animated items outside the Vue mounting element, a workaround is to remove their animation in Vue's [`created` lifecycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#created):

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  new Vue({
    created() {
      document.querySelector('.title').style.setProperty('animation-name', 'none')
    },
  })
}, 3000)
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/oNBOwad)

Comment: Ok, but time 3000 is set for example. If i have mount vue without timeout and set animation for example 2 seconds then i can't clear animation because it may be still running.

Answer (score 0):

## Using templates

Is better if you can use components for this case and add the title with templates.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    template: "<h1 class='show'>Type Something.</h1>",
  });
}, 3000);
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes fadeUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
    transform: translateY(30px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
} 


.show {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeUp;
  animation-name: fadeUp;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

## Using CSS Variables

But if you need to have your HTML rendered before Vue initialize.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="app">
      <h1 class="hidden" 
          :class="{ 'show': isMounted }">
        Type Something. 
      </h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
      isMounted: false
    },
    mounted(){
      this.isMounted = true;
    }
  });
}, 3000);
```

CSS: Important to have the .show specificity greater than the .hidden class

```
@keyframes fadeUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
    transform: translateY(30px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
} 

.hidden{
  opacity: 0;
}

.show {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeUp;
  animation-name: fadeUp;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Like i answered in comment: 
"I can't move content. Page is already running in production. About half of html code is generated with php and half are vue components. "